# Maven filtering - replacement of variables

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a maven project, which generates a jar file as a web project. Based on Maven I include a standalone Tomcat. Inside of the jar file, there is actually the war-file, which contains my application.

This application contains a "version.txt" in src/main/config (or any similar path), that is finally included in the war-file.

This version.txt looks like:

```
version: ${project.version}
```

I would like, that maven should replace the variable with the correct version from pom.xml.
In my pom.xml I have included:

```
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/config</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>**/version.txt</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        <resource>
      <resources>
  </build>
```

So is there any way to include this version.txt and a working replacement in a war-file, which is in a (Tomcat)jar-file?

Addendum:

My File hierarchy looks like:

```
jar-file
-- ...
--war-file
---- ...
----version.txt
```

Comment: Why do you put the `version.txt` into a separate directory `src/main/config` and don't use the default locations like `src/main/resources` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the maven-war-plugin.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

It will expect a certain directory layout, and in the examples it clearly shows how to filter (replace maven variables into the web resources)

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

If this solution falls short, then a more specific question based on this should should be asked later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. No, there was no maven-war-plugin, but I have included it and based on the instructions, it works.

Short solution:

Added a resourceDirectory on same level like `pom.xml` and included `version.txt`

Added in `pom.xml` and activate filtering:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <directory>externalresources</directory>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Maven has a remarkable set of plugins that relieve you of the need to figure out how to do every step individually.  Look into some of the other plugins when you get time.  I would recommend the "site" plugin and then the various site reporting plugins, as there are a nice collection of reports that might help you find bugs before they impact your running programs.