# Insert Spring Boot Server URL into static file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to know if there is a way I can insert the url of a spring boot server into a static file?

So for example i have a file in my resources folder which i would like to write the server url into.

Comment: At which time do you want to define the URL? During build time, during server startup or dynamically (then it's not static)? Maybe look at Maven variable replacement:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908150/maven-filtering-replacement-of-variables

Comment: I needed it in build time, but i have resolved it myself. I had an OpenAPI.yaml spec file which i wanted to use to generate the swagger ui and i thought i had to insert the server url into the yaml file, but now im using redoc and just serve a static html file which uses redoc to create an openapi documentation.